# Android : Google Distance Matrix Error

Tags: android, maps, google-distancematrix-api

I tried to display route, distance and duration using `Distance Matrix` of google from 2 location (it sets by `Latitude` and `longitude`). but it always give me an error like this :

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

here is my url :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origin=-8.60821861,115.18293077&destination=-8.6947,115.263&key=KEY_SERVER
```

but, when i using name of city to set the origin and the destination it works well.
like this :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Bandung&destinations=Jakarta&key=KEY_SERVER
```

the result when using name of city :

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Jakarta, Special Capital Region of Jakarta, Indonesia" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Bandung, Bandung City, West Java, Indonesia" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "94.1 mi",
                  "value" : 151394
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 30 mins",
                  "value" : 8984
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**what should i do to set the origin and destination by `latitude` or `longitude` in order to get the result like above?**

Comment: I hope you have registered on Google Developer console and created a Server key

Comment: what the different if i just use my email addresss?

Comment: Dear Red, email address won't work. Because somethings work as they are programmed to work not how you suppose it to work